# las2dem, command not found in terminal

Tags: qgis, lidar, ubuntu, lastools

I am trying to use the command las2dem in terminal (Ubuntu) to create a DEM with various las files but I only want to conserve the points classified as Ground. I'm using this command:
 `las2dem -i file.las -o dem.png -keep_class 2`

It returns the error: `las2dem:command not found`

I installed LAStools with this command: `conda install -c conda-forge lastools`

I have used other tools from LAStools like txt2las and las2las and I haven't had any problem before, I think there is not a problem with the installation but I'm not sure.

I can use the tool in qgis but I only can add one las file I need to incorporate to the DEM at least 20 las files.

Is there any way to use las2dem from the command line?

Comment: Yes, with the command line `conda activate` also I updated LAStools with `conda update lastools` and the same error is occurring

Comment: You may want to try PDAL: https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html